# NoClassDefFoundError MapView Activity

Tags: android, android-mapview, noclassdeffounderror

I've added a mapview activity to an app, attempting to open the mapView activivty causes a crash. I'm unfamiliar with this problem, and the other threads here about it tend to refer to libs, which I don't seem to have, or class path, which could be the problem but I don't really understand it.

> ```
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.b00517566.weekST.MyMapViewer
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at com.b00517566.weekST.WeekSevenTwoActivity.updateWeatherView(WeekSevenTwoActivity.java:144)
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at com.b00517566.weekST.WeekSevenTwoActivity.access$0(WeekSevenTwoActivity.java:142)
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at com.b00517566.weekST.WeekSevenTwoActivity$1.onClick(WeekSevenTwoActivity.java:63)
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
> 12-12 18:01:26.075: E/AndroidRuntime(4655):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

```
public class MyMapViewer extends MapActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//class begins
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.my_mapview);//sets the layout to the xml

            MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);//creates a new mapview initialisation
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//adds the zoom function to the map

            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();//the mapOverlay listobject is initialised to teh mapView
            Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.station_icon);//points to marker icon
            MyItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);//instantiates Itemizer


            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(54.684624 * 1e6),
                    (int)(-5.880218 * 1e6));//converts double cords to microdegrees for Geopoint
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Jordanstown", "Shore Road, Newtownabbey, Belfast, Antrim BT370QB ");


            GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint((int)(54.66370520273512 * 1e6),
                    (int)(-5.930986404418945 * 1e6));//converts double cords to microdegrees for Geopoint
            OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point1, "Valley JuiJitsu Club", "Valley Park Newtownabbey BT36 6");

            GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint((int)(54.644600844283104 * 1e6),
                    (int)(-5.666391849517822 * 1e6));//converts double cords to microdegrees for Geopoint
            OverlayItem overlayitem3 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Peninsula Martial Arts", "3 Balloo Link, Bangor, Down BT19 7HJ");

            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem); //calls teh addOverlay method
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);//adds above to the itemizedoverlay
         }//end of class





        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }//a necessary generated method
    }
```

The code looks fine to me, so the problem ought to be related to something within the editor or project properties. Any advice on how to go about fixing this would be appreciated.

Manifest

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
>  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>      package="com.b00517566.weekST"
>      android:versionCode="1"
>      android:versionName="1.0" >
>
>      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
>      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
>
>      <application
>          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>          android:label="@string/app_name" >
>          <activity
>              android:name=".WeekSevenTwoActivity"
>              android:label="@string/app_name" >
>
>          </activity>
>          <activity android:name="splash">
>                <intent-filter>
>                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>              </intent-filter>
>          </activity>
>          <activity 
>
>              android:name="MyMapViewer"
>              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
>
>              </activity>
>      </application>
>
>  </manifest>
> ```

```
private void updateWeatherView() {      

startActivity(new Intent(this, MyMapViewer.class));
}//end of method
```

As you can  see its pretty simple, there are no other MyMapViewer classes

Comment: What `package` did you put `MyMapView` in? Did you remember to add this Activity to your Manifest?

Comment: the MyMapView activity is in the same package as the rest, there is only one package. Yes its in the manifest. I'll edit that in too.

Comment: Please post the code to `updateWeatherView()`. Are you accidentally importing some other `MyMapViewer` in `WeekSevenTwoActivity`? (This would probably cause a different exception though...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`

> mainfest add this library

and add permission

```
 <!--permissions -->
     <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
     </uses-permission>
     <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
     </uses-permission>
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't crash. So much appreciated. MapView just shows the grid, an old app I made does this now too, could this be related to google changing the api thing?